# Menu text is still visible on mouseover while sidebar is hidden

Tags: html, css

I'm working on making a sidebar on My main page something like google ventures (https://www.gv.com/lib/how-to-choose-the-right-ux-metrics-for-your-product). but the problem I'm getting is when I click to any menu item in the sidebar , the side bar gets collapse but the text for menu item is still there. I want to keep the sidebar open till the mouse cursor is in the sidebar area (even when user clicks on any menu it should remain opened/expended) but it gets collapse on cliking on any item while the text for the menu item remain in the air. I don't know how to fix it as Im not much hands-on with css and designing.

here is my jquery code for adding classes for collapse/expand the side bar

```
$('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').mouseenter(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("body").hasClass('sidebar-collapse')) {
        $("body").removeClass('sidebar-collapse');
        $("body").addClass('sidebar-open')
    }
});

$('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').mouseleave(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("body").hasClass('sidebar-open')) {
        $("body").removeClass('sidebar-open');
        $("body").addClass('sidebar-collapse')
    };
});
```

and here are css classes (with media queries) for this

```
 .main-sidebar,
 .left-side {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 230px;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out, width 0.3s      ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .main-sidebar,
   .left-side {
     -webkit-transform: translate(-230px, 0);
     -ms-transform: translate(-230px, 0);
     -o-transform: translate(-230px, 0);
     transform: translate(-230px, 0);
   }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar,
 .sidebar-collapse .left-side {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-230px, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-230px, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-230px, 0);
    transform: translate(-230px, 0);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .sidebar-open .main-sidebar,
 .sidebar-open .left-side {
 -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
 -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
 transform: translate(0, 0);
}
}

.sidebar {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

and here is html code where my sidebar resides

```
<aside class="main-sidebar" data-toggle="offcanvas">
 <section class="sidebar">
  <ul class="sidebar-menu">
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
  </ul>
 </section>
<aside>
```

I tried to implement it on mouseclick event by keeping adding the sidebar-open class but this didn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the text in an element like, say `p`'s. Then you can you try hiding the them when mouse leaves and show them when mouse enters. You can add the lines similar to the below ones in your jquery.

```
// on mouse leave
$('ul.sidebar-menu li>p').hide();

// on mouse enter
$('ul.sidebar-menu li>p').show();
```

**Edit ---**

Alternatively you can try the below CSS for `aside.main-sidebar`,

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Thanks @redflar3 solved my problem with white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden; :)